# Check if record exists before submitting new

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I currently have a function which inserts a record into a table with an SQL statement in Access 2010.

```
Sub btnSubmit_Click()

dim strSQL as string

strSQL="INSERT INTO tblMaster (PeriodID,ClassID,ChildID,SubjectID,LevelID) VALUES (" & cboPeriod & "," & cboClass & "," & cboName & "," & tbSubject1 & "," & cboLevel1 & ")"

CurrentDB.Execute strSQL
End Sub
```

What i would like to do first is check to see if 'tblMaster' already has an identical record.

How would i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have imagined there would be a just a few unique identifier's in worst case; the following should work.

```
Sub btnSubmit_Click()
    Dim strSQL as string

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblMaster (PeriodID, ClassID, ChildID, SubjectID, LevelID) VALUES (" & _
                cboPeriod & ", " & cboClass & ", " & cboName & ", " & tbSubject1 & ", " & cboLevel1 & ")"

    If DCount("*", "tblMaster", "PeriodID = " & cboPeriod & " AND " & _
                                "ClassID = " & cboClass & " AND " & _
                                "ChildID = " & cboName & " AND " & _
                                "SubjectID = " & tbSubject1 & " AND " & _
                                "LevelID = " & cboLevel1) = 0 Then
        CurrentDB.Execute strSQL
    Else
        MsgBox "A Record already exists for this information.", vbOKOnly, "No Records Added."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great and works perfectly, however, what if i wanted to check and then insert two or more rows at the same time? is there a clean way to write the code or just a lot of copy and pasting?

Comment: Depends on what you would call clean.. Explain the scenario

Comment: I have a form with 3 combo boxes that are used to filter out a specific pupil. there are then 17 subjects with combo boxes next to them that allow the user to select a level that that specific pupil is attaining at that subject. Each row has a button next to it that allows the user to submit a record if it doesn't already exist, using the code above. What i would like is a button to submit all at the same time. I already have the button that executes 17 Insert Sql commands, but it doesn't yet check to see if the records already exist

Comment: Sounds like a lot of design issues. Have you considered Normalizing your tables to make sure this does not need so much code to work with?

Comment: Sorry, this is all new to me. Ill have a read up on 'normalizing tables'

Answer (score 0):

You can check if that record exists using another select statement.